# My ajax taking too much time in for loop calling a php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My Ajax is taking too much time on  loading am calling ajax from 1 to 3000
It hit on database and get if value exist in database from 1 to 3000  then  it will return
Here's my code

```
function Getdata(e) {
  e = e;
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async: true,
    url: "getdata.php",
    data: "id=" + e,
    success: function(t) {
      jQuery(".reult_get_wish-" + e).html(t.htmltext)
    },
    dataType: "json"
  })
} 

for (var e = 1; e <= 3000; e++) {
  Getdata(e);
}
```

Here's my `getdata.php` file code

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * from wishing_report where user = '".$id."'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
if ($e = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
  echo json_encode($e);
}
```

Comment: Does your ID in mysqli is string? Try user  = " . $id . ";

Comment: SELECT * is not a recommended to be used in sql query.

Comment: Are you braging about? What is your question ?

Answer (score 1):

### Explained

If it takes some time, why not use an asynchronous approach, where you can process 'x' amount at a time, i.e. you could use `setTimeout` and recursion or `setInterval`, just so you can process a block of information/data at a time.

In this example you can see that there's an `onIterate` function and a `onComplete` function, both of these are used in different scenarios, you can use the `onIterate` function for each iteration, prior to the `iterate` function being complete. Once you've iterated enough, this is when you can fire the `onComplete` function, feel free to make any changes you like, i.e. include promises or whatever takes your fancy.

This could also be a better approach for the server as you're allowing the server time to recover from the last request. Alternatively you could alter your back end code so that it's more efficient, etc, you could use some `limit` and `offset` parameter(s) within your query to ensure the server isn't handling **too** much data at one time.

```js
// A function to fire when the ajax request has finished.
const onSuccess = data => {
  console.log(data);
};

// Simulate the ajax request.
const getData = (i, callback) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(i);
    return callback(i);
  }, 500);
}

// A function to fire once complete.
const onComplete = () => console.log('Finished');

// A function to fire if it's not finished/complete. 
const onIterate = () => console.log('NOT finished yet');

// A function to iterate, break the loop up into chuncks. 
const iterate = (start, end, delay) => {
  const process = data => {
    iterate(++start, end, delay)

    if (start > end) {
      onComplete(data);
    } else {
      onIterate(data);
    }
  };

  if (start <= end) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      getData(start, process);
    }, delay);
  }
};

// A starting point. 
const start = () => iterate(0, 10, 1500);

// Just start the function. 
start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Ajax is taking a lot of time beacause you're running it 3000 times. To avoid calling it many times, I recommend putting all ids in array. I would do something like this.

JavaScript:

```
function Getdata(e) {
  e = e;
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    url: "getdata.php",
    data: {id: e},
    success: function(t) {
        $.each(t, function() {
            $.each(this, function(k, v) {
                jQuery(".reult_get_wish-" + v).html(v.htmltext);
            });
        });
    },
    dataType: "json"
  })
}

var arr = [];
for (var e = 1; e <= 3000; e++) {
    arr.push(e);
}

Getdata(arr);
```

PHP:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * from wishing_report where user IN ('".implode(',', $id)."')";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
if ($e = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
  echo json_encode($e);
}
```

Comment: Probably a better suggestion than mine, the only reason why I wrote my solution was due to the fact that I've been in scenarios where the back end is outsourced, but either way, this is probably the best approach, less http requests too!

Comment: Yep, but I don't know how he handle the response

Comment: Touché, that's kinda why I went with the approach I did go for, I mean it partially solves his problem, as he could possibly show a loader/progress bar on the screen which will only hide when the ```onComplete``` function is fired, I mean that's his call I guess? ...

Comment: I think some lazy loading would be great in his case